# OpenGl glm local rotation

Tags: opengl, rotation, quaternions, glm-math

I need to rotate object in local coordinates system, like you can rotate it in 3dmax\maya etc...

My current code is:

```
ModelMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0f);
TransformMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0f);
ScaleMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0f);
RotateMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0f);

ScaleMatrix = glm::scale(ScaleMatrix, glm::vec3(scalex, scalez, scaley));
TransformMatrix = glm::translate(TransformMatrix, glm::vec3(x, z, y));
RotateMatrix = glm::rotate(RotateMatrix, anglex, glm::vec3(1, 0, 0));
RotateMatrix= glm::rotate(RotateMatrix, angley, glm::vec3(0, 0, 1));
RotateMatrix = glm::rotate(RotateMatrix, anglez, glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));

ModelMatrix = TransformMatrix * ScaleMatrix* RotateMatrix;
MVP = Projection * View * ModelMatrix ;
```

anglex,y,z - comes from keyboard.

Right now only last dimension works as local (im my example it's glm::vec3(0, 1, 0) Z axis) At this [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yi8iG.jpg) I show what I needed(2) and what I've got(3)... If I changes "anglez" it's always works as ROLL. But anglex and angley is in the world coordinates system.

The second my attempt - use Quaternions:

```
quat MyQuaternion= glm::quat(cos(glm::radians(xangle / 2)), 0, sin(glm::radians(xangle / 2)), 0);
    quat MyQuaternion2 = glm::quat(cos(glm::radians(yangle/ 2)), sin(glm::radians(yangle / 2)), 0, 0);
    quat MyQuaternion3 = glm::quat(cos(glm::radians(zangle / 2)), 0,0,sin(glm::radians(zangle / 2)));
    glm::mat4 RotationMatrix = toMat4(MyQuaternion*MyQuaternion2*MyQuaternion3);
```

But I have the same result

Answer (score 0):

You should modify the entire `ModelMatrix` instead of the angles. Initialize `ModelMatrix` to the identity matrix. Then, when you process keyboard input:

```
if(rotate about x-axis)
    ModelMatrix = glm::rotate(ModelMatrix, angle, glm::vec3(1, 0, 0));
if(rotate about y-axis)
    ModelMatrix = glm::rotate(ModelMatrix, angle, glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));
if(rotate about z-axis)
    ModelMatrix = glm::rotate(ModelMatrix, angle, glm::vec3(0, 0, 1));
if(any rotation happened)
    MVP = Projection * View * ModelMatrix ;
```

You can do this modification at any level. Either the `MVP` level, the `ModelMatrix` level (as shown here) or the `RotateMatrix` level.

Comment: This way is only works if I don't reset matrix every loop - `//ModelMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0f);`    In this way all my child models can inherit parent model only by multiplication: `ModelMatrix[i] *= TransformMatrix[i] * ScaleMatrix[i]*RotateMatrix[i];`  ... Also in this way I can rotate only strictly along the axes

Comment: Why would you want to reset the matrix? Just use a temporary matrix that accumulates the matrices from your scene graph. Isn't strict axis-constraint rotation what you wanted in the first place? Of course, you can always specify other rotation axes.

Comment: Thank you! I just have not reset only rotation matrix - and it's work fine now. Only specification: `angle=value`  but not the `angle+=value`.